# Apache reverse proxy pod or ingress

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, shibboleth

Currently all my microservices are deployed in single vm.I am planning to dockerize and distribute this in multiple hosts using kubernetes.

But have few queries.

1)Currently I have apache proxy infront which terminates the ssl,use mod_shib to redirect to idp etc.

But in kubernetes I know that we can use ingress.If i use nginx ingress controller can I use the same way to redirect to shibboleth identity provider like apache?.Or should i use apache pod instead of ingress.

2.Can i use apache pod to redirect traffic to cluterip service instead of ingress controller?

I have 9-10 microservices for the application.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same with the Nginx ingress controller however there is also an option available to use the **apache ingress controller**.

[https://github.com/apache/apisix-ingress-controller#:~:text=apisix%2Dingress%2Dcontroller%20is%20an,such%20as%20virtual%20machine%20clusters](https://github.com/apache/apisix-ingress-controller#:%7E:text=apisix%2Dingress%2Dcontroller%20is%20an,such%20as%20virtual%20machine%20clusters).

Comment: Could not find any option in nginx ingress controller..

Comment: option for @SarathS ? POD to direct cluster IP service?

Comment: if you dont want to use ingress controller expose your apache service as loadbalancer and manage the traffic from apache pod internally.

Comment: Yes,that makes sense..in that case hope i can use mod_shib,/etc/shibboleth.conf? also bundled in the pod?